# Is there any way how to get the key (or the whole entry) from a `Map`?

Tags: java, dictionary

Is there any way how to get the key (or the whole entry) from a `HashMap` (or another suitable `Map`) **efficiently**?

Before somebody says, I never need it: I do. I have a loop like this

```
for (long i=0; i<1e12; ++i) {
    Key key = new Key(i);
    Value value = map.get(key);
    if (something(key, value)) list.add(key);
}
```

and my `key` needlessly takes memory which could be saved if I could replace `list.add(key)` by something like  `list.add(map.getKey(key))` (the new instance would be eligible for GC). **While they're equal, reusing the old instance would save memory.**

I know I can embed the key into the value or use Guava's `Interner`; both helps, but both also costs some memory.

---

To address some misunderstanding comments: If efficiency was no issue, the following would do

```
Key getKeyFromMap(Key key, Map<Key, ?> map) {
    for (Key key2 : map.keySet()) {
        if (key.equals(key2)) return key2;
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

The most efficient solution as described in the accepted answer:

```
public static <K, V> K getKey(K key, HashMap<K, V> map) {
    final Entry<K, V> entry = map.getEntry(key);
    return entry==null ? null : entry.getKey();
}
```

The problem is that it must be placed into `package java.util` as it uses a package private method. It can be dangerous to use such a method, but it's no problem in my "run-once" use case.

Comment: `keySet()` seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: I don't get your problem. You create the `Key` object, why would you want to get it from the `Map` after that?

Comment: Why are you searching for the key of a value. It seems like you should use your map in inverse order... Then you can easily find the key of a given value. If this is not possible, save the inverse map in addition to the one you have.

Comment: @nkr: See the highlighted sentence.

Comment: I've seen this question come up time and time again over the years. The sad truth is that there's no proper way to do this with the `Map` interface Java gives you (nor with `Set`, which you would be able to use here via the `keySet`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How much evil are you prepared to commit in order to do this?

The `Map` interface does not let you retrieve a key or an entry. Nor does the `Set` interface. Nor does `HashMap`'s public interface.

But `HashMap`'s *package* interface does (in the Sun JDK, at least). Have a look at [the source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java); at line 355, there is a method called `getEntry` which starts like this:

```
  /**
   * Returns the entry associated with the specified key in the
   * HashMap.  Returns null if the HashMap contains no mapping
   * for the key.
   */
  final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key) {
```

I believe that is exactly what you need. You can call this with reflection, or by sneaking a class of your own into the `java.util` package. The Java maintainers could take this method away in the future, and it might not be present on all platforms, but if you're prepared to hold your nose and take the risk, it's a simple solution.

Comment: Any amount of evil is acceptable, as this is just for a problem from [Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net), so there's no risk at all. It's funny how nearly nobody understood my question.

Comment: Yeah, well that's why some of us have thirteen thousand rep and some don't. BOEM!

Comment: The new signature is `Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key)` - at least in JDK1.8.0_74 (Oracle).

Comment: Not possible anymore with JDK 9+ because of module restrictions. Maybe reflection might work

Answer (score 3):

`NavigableMap` has `ceilingKey`, which would let you use `equals` on the returned Key to see if there is an entry for that exact key. But you couldn't use HashMap, you'd need TreeMap or something, which might negate any memory performance benefits (and your keys would need to implement `Comparable`). Also, the javadoc doesn't say whether the returned key is the exact same object used in the Map, so it might be implementation specific.

Comment: I agree that the `TreeMap` would negate the gain, but it's good to know. In theory, the map could be evil and replace the key found by something else, possibly the argument, but I don't think that anybody  would do it. Even more so for `ceilingEntry`. But this is a good point, too.

Answer (score 3):

I found another workaround, taking advantage of the implementation of the elements (or keys) comparisons in the Collections (or maps).

All collections (or maps) implementations in java.util (as far as I know) are comparing elements by `o.equals(e)` when `o` is the user searched object. So I came up with the following solution:

```
public static <K> K getOriginalKey(final Map<K, ?> map, final K key) {
    OriginalElementExtractor extractor = new OriginalElementExtractor(key);
    map.containsKey(extractor);
    return (K) extractor.result;
}

public static <E> E getOriginalElement(final Collection<E> coll, final E element) {
    OriginalElementExtractor extractor = new OriginalElementExtractor(element);
    coll.contains(extractor);
    return (E) extractor.result;
}

private static class OriginalElementExtractor {

    final Object key;
    final int hash;
    Object result;

    OriginalElementExtractor(final Object key) {
        this.key = key;
        hash = key.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        boolean eq;
        if (eq = key.equals(o))
            result = o;
        return eq;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return hash;
    }
}
```

The Collection (or map) will invoke the `OriginalElementExtractor.equals(Object)` method to check for equality, and the original element will be passed.

Comment: This is awesome but Clever in a Bad Way.  (upvoted anyhow)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: What I think you want to do is test memory-efficient if a `key-Object` is a key in you `Map`:

```
Key getKeyFromMap(Key key, Map<Key, ?> map) {
  if(map.containsKey(key){
    return key;
  }else{
    return null;
  }
}
```

Old Answer:

```
Map<String, Value> map = new HashMap<>();//Java 7 diamond operator.
Set<String> keySet = map.keySet();

for(String key: keySet){
  System.out.println(key + " is key in the map");
}
Object[] keyArray = keySet.toArray();
```

`Map#keySet()`returns a `Set` containing all used keys in the map. you can iterate through your Set. A Set is not ordered like your `Map` is not, too. But you can convert it to an Array with `Set#toArray()` returning an Array of Objects wich can be casted to the generic type of the `Set`.

Comment: Yes, it does... and now the next question: How do I get the key from the `keySet`? I mean efficiently (iterating doesn't count).

Comment: there is no "THE key", there is an unordered group of keys. How do you want to get "THE one"? It's impossible without an `Iterator`.

Comment: If efficiency was no issue, iterating through the `keySet` would do, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

You want the entry set it seems.

```
for (Entry<Key,Value> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (something(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())) {
        list.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

You're not going to get better than that without leveraging some information about the data you're got.

In addition, the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you approach it like this.

```
    for (Iterator i = map.keySet().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        String key = (String) i.next();
        if (key.equals(value)) {
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but it would takes years, as the map contains some millions entries and I do some billions of lookups.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the `Key` to a given `Value`, there are three possibilities:

1. Iterate over the key set and find the key to your value (bad runtime).
2. Save the inverse map in addition to your original map (Value -> Key) (double space consumption)
3. Use Guava's [`HashBiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashBiMap.html) which has a method `inverse`. It will return the inverse of your map. Then you can simply use `inverse.get(value)` to get your key.

Comment: I don't want find key by the value. I have a key, but I want exactly the instance which is stored in the map. While they're equal, by reusing the instance I can save a lot of memory.

Comment: @maaartinus Then you can either use possibility (1), or you can save an additional map where the key is some unique id and the value is your `Key` object. There really is nothing else you can do. By the way: Where did you get the key from (the one you have, but don't want to use)? Shouldn't it be identical to the one in the map?

Comment: The key I'm using for the lookup was just newly created, it  `equals` to the one in the map, but it isn't `==` to it. The answer by Tom Anderson solves it.

Comment: Consider using a canonicalizing map (ie. `WeakHashMap<T,WeakReference<T>> canonicalMap`) alongside your value map...  this will work even if the mapping is non-injective.

Answer (score 0):

I've not find a good solution for this, so finish embed the key into the value as you say like this:

```
    Map<K, Entry<K, V>> map = new HashMap<K, Entry<K, V>>();
    K key = new K(...);
    map.put(key, new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K, V>(key, value));

    //then I can retrieve the reference of original key, given another instance of de key
    Entry<K, V> keyObj = map.get(new K(...));
```