# How to get a specific Map.Entry<K, V> for a specific key?

Tags: java, subclassing, linkedhashmap

I'm implementing a `NavigableMap`-implementing `LinkedHashMap` in Java.  (There don't seem to be many (any?) reasons why `LinkedHashMap` doesn't implement `NavigableMap` already, but I digress...)

I've written `lowerKey()`, `lowerEntry()`, `higherKey()`, and `higherEntry()` by iterating the `entrySet()`.  I don't see any way in these cases to avoid iterating the entire `entrySet()`.

For `floorKey()`, `floorEntry()`, `ceilingKey()`, and `ceilingEntry()`, in the case that the key exists, I'd like to avoid the expense of iterating the `entrySet()`, considering that I can already get the value with plain-old `get()`.

***Is there a way to get the `Map.Entry` for a particular key, rather than just the value?***  Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense for `LinkedHashMap` to implement `NavigableMap` because it isn't sorted - it is ordered by insertion order. Unless you have some other notion of `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: The contract of `NavigableMap` appears to depend on the `Map` being **ordered**, not **sorted**.

Comment: Are you aware that `NavigableMap` inherits from `SortedMap`?

Comment: I hadn't noticed that, but it doesn't really affect my purposes.

Comment: Moreover, even `SortedMap` appears to depend on **ordering** and not necessarily **sorting**.

Comment: It appears there's sneaky way of doing this, tho I'm not sure if `getEntry` is removed now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769606/is-there-any-way-how-to-get-the-key-or-the-whole-entry-from-a-map

Comment: what does it mean when you say higherEntry?  can you provide example?

Comment: @ChengThao What I mean by `higherEntry()` is https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#higherEntry(K)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Sweeper's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper) comment on his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73341523/3605497) got me thinking.  The solution I came up with was to maintain a `Map` from `Key` to `Entry` inside my class.  That way I have a way of having `O(1)` access to the `entrySet`.  Like so:

```
Map<K, Map.Entry<K, V>> entryMap = new HashMap<>();
for(final currentEntry : entrySet())
{
    entryMap.put(currentEntry.getKey(), currentEntry);
}
```

I just need to update this `Map` every time an operation runs which changes the `keySet`.  I only need to update the one entry in this `Map` that would be affected.  That sounds like it wouldn't be very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You have the key, and you can get the value associated with the key using `get`, now all you gotta do is to make a `Map.Entry`, and we can do that with the [`Map.entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#entry(K,V)) factory method:

```
var value = theBackingLinkedHashMap.get(key);
if (value == null) {
    return null;
}
return Map.entry(key, value);
```

The entry returned by `entry` does have two caveats that you should be aware of:

- does not allow null keys, so your `NavigableLinkedHashMap` would need to not allow null keys either
- is immutable, so you cannot call `setValue`.

But other than that, it will work as if you got the `Map.Entry` from inside the backing `LinkedHashMap`, and it does fulfil the contract of `ceilingEntry`, `floorEntry` etc, since they just ask for a "*a* key-value mapping", and doesn't require that it has to have the mutability as the map itself or anything like that. For example, this is `ceilingEntry`:

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the least key greater than or equal to the given key, or null if there is no such key.

Comment: The second is my main concern with this method. If someone is iterating the `entrySet()` and uses `setValue()` on an entry, I want it to be able to update the `Map`

Comment: @TrippKinetics For `entrySet` and other `Map` methods, you can just delegate to the `LinkedHashMap` implementation, can’t you? You only need to create your own entries in methods such as `ceilingEntry` and `floorEntry`. The whole idea is that, unlike `entrySet`, it is a lot less common to need to call `setValue` on methods such as `ceilingEntry` and `floorEntry`, so this implementation could still satisfy a large number of use cases in despite of this.

Comment: Let me give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would use TreeSet to keep the keys in the NavigableMap class.  See example below:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NavMap<Integer, String> map = new NavMap<>();
        map.put(1, "one");
        map.put(2, "two");
        map.put(3, "three");
        map.put(4, "four");
        map.put(10, "ten");
        System.out.println(map.lowerKey(3));    //2
        System.out.println(map.higherKey(3));   //4
        System.out.println(map.higherEntry(3));  // 4:four
        System.out.println(map.ceilingKey(7));  //10
        System.out.println(map.floorKey(7));    //4
        System.out.println(map.floorEntry(10)); // 4:four
        
    }
}

class NavMap<K extends Comparable,V extends Comparable> extends LinkedHashMap<K,V>{
   private TreeSet<K> keys    = new TreeSet<>();
   
   public Set<K> keySet(){ return keys; }
   
   public K lowerKey  (K k){ return keys.lower(k);  }
   public K higherKey (K k){ return keys.higher(k); }
   public K floorKey  (K k){ return keys.floor(k);  }
   public K ceilingKey(K k){ return keys.ceiling(k);}
   
   public Map.Entry<K,V> lowerEntry(K k)   { return newEntry(lowerKey(k),  get(lowerKey(k)));}
   public Map.Entry<K,V> higherEntry(K k)  { return newEntry(higherKey(k), get(higherKey(k)));}
   public Map.Entry<K,V> floorEntry(K k)   { return newEntry(floorKey(k),  get(floorKey(k)));}
   public Map.Entry<K,V> ceilingEntry(K k) { return newEntry(ceilingKey(k),get(ceilingKey(k)));}
   private Map.Entry<K,V> newEntry(K k, V v) { return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(k,v);} 
   
   public V put(K key, V value){
      keys.add(key);
      return super.put(key, value);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
2
4
4=four
10
4
10=ten
```

Comment: I just realize the Map.keySet() probably returns a TreeSet.  In that case, you won't need to keep another TreetSet of keys in NavigableMap.

Comment: Actually, the above comment is wrong.  LinkedHashMap.keySet() returns LinkedHashMap.LinkedKeySet.

Comment: This won't work because the `TreeSet` won't keep the keys in the same order as a `LinkedHashSet`.

Comment: This gives me an idea though.  Instead of just subclassing `LinkedHashMap`, maybe I should subclass `LinkedHashSet` also.  Comments?

Comment: @TrippKinetics I updated the code.  Check to see if it's all there.

Comment: Nope.  Still won't work because the `TreeSet` will not preserve the key order of the `LinkedHashMap`.